# How to get assisted gps / A-GPS disabled event in android programmatically

Tags: android

How to get the event when assisted gps is disabled in android . I don't know how to get the event. Please help me out.

Comment: I want to get the event when it is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not enable assisted gps or gps programmatically in in higher version of android it will give security exception . instead you can direct user to enable it,

Comment: Can u please suggest me how to get the event when a-gps is disabled.